# Indexing a document into elasticsearch with ndjson format

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, ndjson

The question is also posted here,

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/indexing-jupyter-notebooks/194639?u=venkateshreddypala

Comment: Please, update your question with your problem, what you are trying to do, what you have tried, what you expect the result to be and the error you are getting, avoid posting links to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit the question that I already have posted but here's the context, I have Jupyter notebooks which needs to be indexed and Jupyter notebooks are ndjson files on the background. But the content I am trying to index and query is wrapped inside a block of \n  used for the format of notebooks. How do I index only the feilds that I want to? avoiding the above